# Fail mocha test in catch block of rejected promise

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, axios, chai

How to fail the test in catch block of promise rejection when making http call using axios?
Adding expectations, asserts, should expressions in catch block doesn't help.
The test is passing.

I's run using *`.\node_modules\.bin\mocha`*

```
let chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;

var axios = require('axios')
var instance = axios.create({})

    describe('test', () => {

        context('test', () => {

        it('should succeed', () => {
            let url = 'url'
            instance.get(url)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        expect(response.data).not.to.be.null
                    } )
                    .catch(function(err) {
                        console.error(err.data) 
                        // should fail the test                                          
                    })


        })

        })
    })
```

Comment: I am not sure if I get Your idea correctly? You would like to assert if err is defined in that particular case or would like to fail test at all in case of `err`?

Comment: thanks. to fail test at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If You want to verify my suggestions, replace url value with valid url (ex: https://google.com)

You can try several ways:

1) **Using assert.fail()**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { assert, expect } = require('chai');

const instance = axios.create({})

describe('test', () => {
  context('test', () => {
    it('should succeed', () => {
      let url = 'abc'
      return instance.get(url)
        .then((res) => { 
          expect(res.data).not.to.be.null;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          assert.fail('expected', 'actual', err);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

2) **Using done() with error object**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { expect } = require('chai');

const instance = axios.create({})

describe('test', () => {
  context('test', () => {
    it('should succeed', (done) => {
      let url = 'abc'
      instance.get(url)
        .then((res) => { 
          expect(res.data).not.to.be.null;
          done();
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          done(err);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

3) **Simply just throw an error :)**

```
const axios = require('axios');
const { expect } = require('chai');

const instance = axios.create({})

describe('test', () => {
  context('test', () => {
    it('should succeed', () => {
      let url = 'abc'
      return instance.get(url)
        .then((res) => { 
          expect(res.data).not.to.be.null;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          throw err;
        });
    });
  });
})
```

If You want to check if that method fails at all and You expect this, go that way (it requires chai-as-promised package):

```
const axios = require('axios');
const chai = require('chai');

chai.use(require('chai-as-promised'));
const instance = axios.create({})

describe('test', () => {
  context('test', () => {
    it('should succeed', () => {
      let url = 'abc'
      return chai.expect(instance.get(url)).to.be.rejected;
    });
  });
});
```